# Not able to call NewAPI for QuickBlox iOS 2.0+

Tags: ios, quickblox

I'm using Quickblox SDK and developing iOS based app.

Currently, I'm not able to use new API (block statement).
I have to use the deprecated one, delegate way.

This happened when I tried to call create session with NewAPI format

```
[QBRequest createSessionWithSuccessBlock:^(QBResponse *response, QBASession *session) {
    NSLog(@"Successfull response!");
} errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {
    NSLog(@"Response error: %@", response.error);
}];
```

It returned

```
+[QBRequest createSessionWithSuccessBlock:errorBlock:]: 
  unrecognized selector sent to class 0x2a5798  
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', 
  reason: '+[QBRequest createSessionWithSuccessBlock:errorBlock:]: 
  unrecognized selector sent to class 0x2a5798'
```

---

But I able to call using the deprecated way

```
[QBAuth createSessionWithDelegate:self context:testContext];
```

which I have handled with

```
-(void)completedWithResult:(Result *)result context:(void *)contextInfo { }
```

---

I quite sure that I followed [iOS SDK Integration](http://quickblox.com/developers/IOS)
The SDK version is 2.0.10

What wrong should I fix to work with new API?

Answer (score 3):

I was having exactly the same problem in a Swift project of mine. In my case I fixed it by adding `-ObjC` to `Other Linker Flags` in my build settings.

Comment: I've already added it because it is mentioned in [this guide](http://quickblox.com/developers/IOS-how-to-connect-Quickblox-framework). More solution would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

I'm using Quickblox and createSessionWithSuccessBlock works as expected.

Please try to setup Quickblox with CocoaPods and see if error happens again

http://quickblox.com/developers/IOS-how-to-connect-Quickblox-framework#CocoaPods